# Class into a timeit function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, time, timeit

I have to make a class with a couple of methods in it but at the end I have to measure 5 times of duration.

I was thinking about this code but I don't know if it's possible to add class into a `timeit.timeit` statement.

```
class MyExcercise(Thread):
    def run():
        i = 0
        while i <= 10000000:
            i+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    for _ in range(5):
        a = timeit.timeit(MyExcercise(??????), number=1)
        print(f'Time a is to: {a: .3f} second(s)')
```

How can I make this code ready to use with class? (for now it's only error)

Later I have to multiply a thread and a number of processes but for now, how can I deal with it?

Edit:

Code works without class (but I have to do this with class).

```
def run():
    i = 0
    while i <= 10000000:
        i+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    for _ in range(5):
        a = timeit.timeit(run, number=1)
        print(f'Time a is to: {a: .3f} second(s)')


Time a is to:  0.238 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.247 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.260 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.248 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.250 second(s)
```

Edit 2:

Yes, my task is to measure my process with one thread, then with 4 threads, next in 4 processors in my computer.

Comment: What does `measure 5 times of duration` mean?

Comment: Can you add the clarifications to the question with proper formatting?

Comment: okej, I edited it

Comment: I have to measure the execution time of this code five times

Comment: Are you threading? If so a lot changes. Just searching on this, here is what I am thinking "timeit() runs in it's own scope, so you need to import anything you need into that scope using the setup parameter for the Timer() constructor".  Threading is how people lose eyes if they are not experienced, friendly warning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `globals()` as `global` parameter in the `timeit` method.

```
import timeit


class MyExercise():
    def run(__self__):
        i = 0
        while i <= 10000000:
            i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(5):
        a = timeit.timeit("MyExercise().run()", globals=globals(), number=1)
        print(f'Time a is to: {a: .3f} second(s)')
```

**Output:**

```
Time a is to:  0.387 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.383 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.382 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.381 second(s)
Time a is to:  0.382 second(s)
```

**References:**

- [Python documentation on timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)